# summation notation for general sets

Tags: notation, game-theory, economics

I'm working through an academic game theory paper and stumbled upon this summation notation in a proof and I'm not quite sure what it means:

$$\sum\limits_{j \in M \backslash\ \{i\}}$$

There is a set $M$ indexed by $j$. There are other terms in the expression indexed by $i$. I'm curious what the $\backslash\{i\}$ means. Does this mean "with the exception of $i$"?

This context is an actor ($i$)'s utility function that depends on what other actors in the set $M$ do. Other actors are indexed by $j$.

Comment: Yes. This means "$j\in M$ and $j\neq i$".

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd translate the notation as "summation over all $j$'s such that $j \in M$ and $j \neq i$".

Answer (score 0):

Let X be a set and A be a subset of X, X\A = {x in X: x is not an element of A}.